# How can an All-Pairs Shortest Path algorithm be optimized for an undirected symmetric graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

How can an All-Pairs Shortest Path algorithm be optimized for an undirected symmetric graph?

I came across this question as a result of a misunderstanding of another question and I thought it might be of interest to someone.

All-Pairs Shortest Paths is probably a more interesting question, but feel free to mention Single-Source Shortest Path if you see a significant optimization there.

I'm not looking for a comparison of Shortest Path algorithms, unless you specifically focus on symmetric graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hopefully explain things better, I'll use a metaphor of a butterfly (assuming the wings are symmetric).

Common vertices: all vertices that make up the line of symmetry (thus the body of the butterfly).

**Algorithm:**

- Remove from the graph all vertices that lie on one of the symmetric sides (and their connected edges)

  *Remove one of the wings of the butterfly.*
- Run any shortest path algorithm on this new graph
- You now have the shortest paths from/to all common vertices to/from all other vertices (since the graph is undirected and all removed vertices have a symmetric vertex in this new graph, which has the same distance to common vertices)

  *You now have the shortest path from/to the body of the butterfly to/from any point on either wing. This is because the distance from some point on the body of the butterfly to some point on a wing is the same as the distance from that point on the body to the same point on the other wing, which is also the same distance as the reverse path of either of these.*
- Now, for each non-common vertex `a`, each other non-common vertex `b` and each common vertex `c`, record the distance from `a` to `c` to `b` (constant time operation (just addition) since we already have the distance from `a` to `c` and from `c` to `b`).
  The minimum distance from `a` to the symmetric vertex of `b` (or the symmetric vertex of `a` to `b`) will be the minimum such distance among all common vertices.

  *To determine the shortest path from any point on one wing to any point on the other wing, we check all paths from the first point to each point on the body and from each point on the body to the second point, and find the smallest such distance.*

Comment: I.o.w., the body is a [vertex separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_separator).